# Grouping the elements of an object. (underscore.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an object as shown below :

```
[
{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"AA","ControlGroupName":"1"},
{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"BB","ControlGroupName":"1"},
{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"CC","ControlGroupName":"1"},
{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"DD","ControlGroupName":"2"},
{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"EE","ControlGroupName":"3"},
{"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"FF","ControlGroupName":"1"},
{"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"GG","ControlGroupName":"1"},
{"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"HH","ControlGroupName":"2"}
]
```

I need to group it like this :

```
 [    
    [
        [
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"AA","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"BB","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"CC","ControlGroupName":"1"}
        ],
        [{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"DD","ControlGroupName":"2"}],
        [{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"EE","ControlGroupName":"3"}]
    ],
    [
        [
         {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"FF","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"GG","ControlGroupName":"1"}
        ],
        [{"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"HH","ControlGroupName":"2"}]
    ]    
]
```

I am using `underscore.js` to group the elements in the object.

```
 $scope.InitController = function () {      

   ClientGroupService.GetClientGroupList().then(function (response) {    
    $scope.groupByTwoFields = [];
    $scope.groupByTwoFields = _.groupBy(response.data, function (obj) {
                    return obj.ClientGroupName  + '|' + obj.ControlGroupName;
                });
       .....
   });
};
```

The output from the above code looks like :

```
[   
        [
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"AA","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"BB","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"CC","ControlGroupName":"1"}
        ],
        [{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"DD","ControlGroupName":"2"}],
        [{"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"EE","ControlGroupName":"3"}],  
        [
         {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"FF","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"GG","ControlGroupName":"1"}
        ],
        [{"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"HH","ControlGroupName":"2"}]   
]
```

What do I need to do in order to get the desired output as shown above.

Your code producing the output in the below shown form  :

```
  [ 
        [
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"AA","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"BB","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"CC","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"DD","ControlGroupName":"2"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"EE","ControlGroupName":"3"}
        ],  
        [
         {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"FF","ControlGroupName":"1"},
         {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"GG","ControlGroupName":"1"},
        {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"HH","ControlGroupName":"2"}]    
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple function to do it in vanilla JavaScript, it takes two arguments:
`arr` The array containing the objects that you want to group.
`properties` An array of strings with the names of the properties you want to group the objects by, ordered by priority (objects will be ordered by the first property in the array, then the second, etc).

```
function groupByProperties(arr, properties) {
    const groups = {
        root: {
            array: [],
            children: {}
        }
    };

    arr.forEach(obj => {
        let group = groups.root;
        properties.forEach(propertyKey => {
            const property = obj[propertyKey];
            if (!group.children.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                const child = {
                    array: [],
                    children: {}
                }
                group.array.push(child.array);
                group.children[property] = child;
            }
            group = group.children[property];
        });
        group.array.push(obj);
    });
    return groups.root.array;
}
```

You would use it as follows:

```
let data = [
    {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"AA","ControlGroupName":"1"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"BB","ControlGroupName":"1"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"CC","ControlGroupName":"1"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"DD","ControlGroupName":"2"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"EE","ControlGroupName":"3"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"FF","ControlGroupName":"1"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"GG","ControlGroupName":"1"},
    {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"HH","ControlGroupName":"2"}
];

console.log(groupByProperties(data, ["ClientGroupName", "ControlGroupName"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

i did it with just vanillaJS in case the answer above didn't work for you:

```
var data = [

        {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"AA","ControlGroupName":"1"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"BB","ControlGroupName":"1"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"CC","ControlGroupName":"1"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"DD","ControlGroupName":"2"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"ABC","CompanyName":"EE","ControlGroupName":"3"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"FF","ControlGroupName":"1"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"GG","ControlGroupName":"1"},

        {"ClientGroupName":"DEF","CompanyName":"HH","ControlGroupName":"2"}

    ];



    var ClientGroupNames = [];

    data.forEach(function(o){

        if(ClientGroupNames.indexOf(o.ClientGroupName) < 0){

            ClientGroupNames.push(o.ClientGroupName);

        }

    });

    var result = ClientGroupNames.map(function(name){

        return data.filter(function(comp){

            return comp.ClientGroupName == name ? true : false;

        })

    }).map(function(grp){

        var groupNames = [];

        grp.forEach(function(company){

            if(groupNames.indexOf(company.ControlGroupName) < 0)

                groupNames.push(company.ControlGroupName);

        })

        return groupNames.map(function(name){

            return grp.filter(function(gp){

                return gp.ControlGroupName == name ? true : false;

            })

        })
    })
```

Comment: getting  ReferenceError: ob is not defined

Comment: replace the ob with data, its fixed now

Comment: Thank you. but the result is not the way I want.  Your code is grouping by 'ClientGroupName'. After grouping by 'ClientGroupName' I want that data to be grouped by 'ControlGroupName' .

Comment: The output of your code looks like the output at the end of the question.

Comment: no its not, please check again. and why you commenting the same stuff on both answers

Comment: I tried both and I got the same results hence I commented the same on both answers.

Comment: on console.log I do see the output correctly.  But in my cshtml page for some reason it is different.

Answer (score 2):

_.groupBy doesn't return an array, it returns an object.

```
   var data = [{
  "ClientGroupName": "ABC",
  "CompanyName": "AA",
  "ControlGroupName": "1"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "ABC",
  "CompanyName": "BB",
  "ControlGroupName": "1"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "ABC",
  "CompanyName": "CC",
  "ControlGroupName": "1"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "ABC",
  "CompanyName": "DD",
  "ControlGroupName": "2"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "ABC",
  "CompanyName": "EE",
  "ControlGroupName": "3"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "DEF",
  "CompanyName": "FF",
  "ControlGroupName": "1"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "DEF",
  "CompanyName": "GG",
  "ControlGroupName": "1"
}, {
  "ClientGroupName": "DEF",
  "CompanyName": "HH",
  "ControlGroupName": "2"
}];

var obj = _.groupBy(data,function (obj) {
    return obj.ClientGroupName;
}); // groupBy returns an object, not a array
var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; }); // this converts the object to an array

_.each(result,function(obj,index){ // loop through each item in the array
  var _obj = _.groupBy(obj,function(obj2){
    return obj2.ControlGroupName;
  }); // group it by the ControlBroupName and convert it to a array
  result[index] = Object.keys(_obj).map(function (key) { return _obj[key]; });

});

console.log("result:\n", result);
```

Comment: Thank you. but the result is not the way I want. Your code is grouping by 'ClientGroupName'. After grouping by 'ClientGroupName' I want that data to be grouped by 'ControlGroupName' .

Comment: The output of your code looks like the output at the end of the question.

Comment: @rmkr are you sure you are view the results correctly? Here's the code in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t8gd47sr/

Comment: When I do the Console.log I do see the results as shown in your jsfiddle. But on my view it is showing the different results.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="(key, item) in groupByTwoFields [0]  track by $index">
            <div> {{item}}</div>

Comment: @rmkr the issue is also with your template, not with the javascript code.

Comment: could you please  tell what is the  issue you see with the template?

Answer (score 1):

You have to `groupBy` twice:

```
result = _(data).groupBy('ClientGroupName').map(g =>
    _.values(_.groupBy(g, 'ControlGroupName'))
).value()
```